# what is the max voltage that a cordless phone may handle above its original rate?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, linear

I am familiar with the fact that,today,most of the cordless phones have
smps adaptors,which supplies a constant voltage to the base unit(opposed to the unregulated linear adaptors,which their rated voltage varies accordingly to the current load).I am,also,familiar that too much input voltage may cause heating of the electronic components in the base unit,may reduce their life or cause them to fail.My question is,as a rule of thumb/in general,How much voltage,in percentage,can the cordless phone handle,beyond its original rated voltage,without having an adverse effects,as i mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard answer to this. Some will have voltage and charging regulators built into the phone so the external power supply is just that - it's technically not a charger. The cordless phones don't have any standards so the charger may be in the phone, in the base or in the wall adapter.

Comment: ,the voltage and charging regulators,which built into the phones are feeded from the wall adaptor.Those electronic components in the base unit or wherever they are located,are designed to work at a rated voltage and may work fine above the rated voltage,but until a limit value(heating issue).What is,in general,the limit?(+10%,+20%...from the rated voltage)

Comment: generally 5% often more than that.